# Point tracking Emgu cv?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

how do i track points in a video in real time like in the below video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg6Nz6BfoSQ

I managed to use optical flow method to get this output to my video,
[image]

But i couldn't find a way to point track with Emgu Cv. Can someone suggest what should I do?

In youTube video he used c++ as the language.Does the language type affect to the real time response of the system?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the floor coordinates (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx) there is an API function. You can also get raw depth stream data and determine the 3D coordinates of a point. To make 3D point cloud it is a litle expensive usualy done on GPU for real time applications. The problem is that you have to track objects. For tracking you can check OpenCV and to combine it with kinect raw data.